# Доступ к двумерному массиву через указатели

Tags: массивы, указатели, c++

Мне нужно выводить на экран массив размером около 1000x1000 . Если постоянно обращаться к элементам массива через [][] , это занимает долго времени. Хочу сделать через указатели. Так же должно быть быстрее. Как лучше сделать пробег по такому массиву с наименьшим временем через указатели?

Comment: Нет, так не должно быть быстрее. Вас кто-то дезинформировал.

Comment: Можно потрахаться, выделить память одним куском, потом сгенерить массив указателей, расставить их по этому куску памяти и итерироваться так, как говорит @aknew про статический массив. Получится одно разыменование вместо двух, и это хорошо. Но стоит ли игра свечь? Еще раз повторюсь, вывод в 90% случаев медленнее доступа.

http://codepaste.net/oddae7

Comment: Иначе, выделяя динамическом массиве, выделяя строки отдельно, они у тебя будут храниться отдельно. Т.е. сначала нужно найти указатель на нужную строку (один раз разыменовали), затем со смещением разыменовываем и указатель на конкретный элемент (два). Косвенное обращение дольше, чем непосредственное, потому, чем меньше разыменований, тем лучше.

Comment: Массив создается динамически через new. Я хотел записать в указатель адрес первого элемента в массиве p=&mas[0][0]. И дальше не использовать оператор [].И инкрементируя p двигаться по памяти. И когда в конце строки нужно перейти на следующую строку ,можно ли это как-то сделать не используя p=&mas[1][0]. а как -то высчитать количество ячеек через кооторые нужно перепрыгнуть?

Скорость увеличивается за счет того что не нужно на каждом элементе искать начало массива потом делать сдвиг чтоб найти нужный элемент

Comment: @Dexter384
Чтобы без указателей на начало строки переходить с одной строки на другую, вычисляя только смещение от элемента (0;0), тебе необходимо точно знать, где начинается следующая строка. Если ты делаешь new для каждой строки, то ты этого знать не можешь, ибо стандартным аллокатором управляет БОХ!

Comment: Free_ze, код который вы выложили http://codepaste.net/oddae7 . это способ быстрого доступа к элементам? я не понял алгоритм ,который там описан

Comment: @Dexter384 Да. Повторю еще раз: память выделяется один раз для всей матрицы строкой (одномерный массив или "буфер"). Строка за строкой, т.е. за крайним элементом каждой строки идет первый элемент следующей. Также мы создаем массив указателей на строки (чтобы так де удобно, как и раньше можно было ходить arr[i][j]), циклом заставляем указывать их на первый элемент каждой строки. В итоге: мы можем перемещаться быстро используя синтаксис arr[i+j] и по-старому, но дольше - arr[i][j].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ты думаешь, если был бы выигрыш, то компилятор не догадался бы оптимизировать ptr[ i ][ j ] как

```
*( *( prt + i ) + j )
```

?

Да и, с большой долей вероятности, боттлнеком у тебя будут именно функции вывода, а не доступа.

Comment: только не ((a+i)+j) , а ((a+i*length)+j), где length - длинна одной строки. Но в целом все верно - компилятор и сам прекрасно справляется с такими оптимизациями, а читаемость кода скорее всего упадет

Comment: @aknew
Вы считаете, что строки двумерного массива обязательно идут друг за другом?

Comment: именно так, память одномерна, так что двумерные массивы по дефолту это куча одномерных записаных друг за другом. Я правда не помню строки там или столбцы если честно.
По вашей же формуле невозможно отличить a[2][5] от a[5][2]

Comment: @aknew Вы обратили внимание на операторы разыменования в моем коде?
Вопрос на засыпку: выделяя память динамически, вы создаете массив указателей, затем, по каждому из этих указателей выделяете буфер памяти. Вопрос: будут ли эти буферы располагаться один за другим? Есть ли разница в порядке создания этих буферов? И, наконец, как себя там поведет ваш код?

Comment: нет, разименование прозевал, каюсь. По поводу второго - мы же про статику говорим, иначе наши с вами фразы про умный компилер теряют смысл. Для динамики, насколько я понимаю, у нас есть массив указателей на первые элементы массивов-строк (расположеных не по порядку в массиве, а по порядку выделения и строго говоря даже не в одной области памяти) и располагается все это добро в куче (а вот статические могут быть и в стеке). Только тогда можно еще сказать и "а что если вместо массива будет список?" и тогда адресная арифметика вообще будет курить в сторонке

Comment: @aknew Оптимизация возможна даже на стадии компиляции, ибо квадратные скобки - это ничто иное, как синтаксический сахар к моему способу. А вот ваш способ - да, по-быстрее будет.

Comment: @Free_ze, описываемая Вами динамическая структура (вектор указателей на строки матрицы) по большому счету не может называться [массивом](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29).

Comment: @avp
Пожалуйста, внимательно читайте свои же пруфы (раздел с примерами).
Да и давненько есть такое понятие, как [Jagged array ли ступенчатый массив][1]

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array

Comment: @Free_ze, не понял, что Вы посоветовали мне внимательно изучить (оставаясь в рамках C/C++), но Ваш пример с массивом (вектором) указателей это не совсем ступенчатый массив (поэтому я и не стал использовать в комментарии этот термин), т.к. в нем (ступенчатом массиве) строки могут быть разной длины, а в описанной Вами реализации нет (правда можно легко  реализовать отсутствие некоторых строк) -- размер у всех д.б. одинаков (в крайнем случае он может быть функцией от индекса строки).

--

Подводя итог. Все элементы *массива* (в С/С++) должны занимать *последовательные* адреса в памяти.

Answer (score 3):

А почему вы уверены, что это даст прирост производительности? Ведь объявление вида

```
#define WIDTH 1000
#define HEIGHT 1000

int a[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

практически аналогично (если не принимать во внимание фрагментацию памяти и алгоритмы аллокатора) вот этому:

```
int ** a = new int*[WIDTH];
for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
    a[i] = new int[HEIGHT];
}
```

Объявления массивов через указатели имеет смысл только если вы заранее (на стадии компиляции) не знаете размер массива и вынуждены выделять память динамически. А вот что действительно может ускорить работу с двумерным массивом, так это объявление его как одномерного и доступ к его элементам через адресную арифметику:

```
int a[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
a[i * WIDTH + j];
```

Эта запись аналогична этой:

```
int a[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
a[i][j];
```

Comment: @fori1ton, может это и зависит от компилятора, но для большинства скорость доступа что к 

    a[i * WIDTH + j];

что к

    a[i][j];

будет одинакова.

--

Но, сей прием крайне полезно помнить для гибкой работы с матрицами, передавемыми как параметр в функцию.

Comment: @avp, мне кажется, что нет. В первом случае будет два чтения из памяти, а во втором одно.

Comment: @dzhioev, это как?

Если  предположить, что речь идет о локальных переменных и `WIDTH` известна во время компиляции, то в обеих случаях потребуется извлечь из память только `i` и `j` (ну, и машинные инструкции с закодированными константами (`WIDTH` (при записи `a[i][j]` константа  `WIDTH` это размер строки, она известна компилятору, но явно в тексте программы не присутствует), `sizeof(a[0][0])` и смещение `a[0][0]` от `fp` (stack frame pointer)).

Т.е. и там и там **3 обращения** (считая выборку `a[i][j]`).

Answer (score 3):

Раз тут пошла такая пьянка, расскажу немного про указатели, которые указывают на двумерные массивы в памяти.

```
int**  mat  = new int*[N];
```

Вот здесь будет выделено n-ое число указателей, которые следуют друг за другом (проверить можете легко).

```
ptrdiff_t diff = (mat + N) - mat;
```

Далее мы выделяем память для этих `mat[n] = PTR` указателей, ведь диспетчер памяти не обязан выделять память строго друг за другом потому, что это не противоречит самой идеи указателей (здесь фрагментация как таковая роли не играет). 
Возьмём, к примеру, разряжённую матрицу, в которой каждая строка это односвязной список.

```
node** mat = new node*[N];
m[0] - здесь связной список
m[1] - здесь связной список
m[n]...
```

А вот пример, как пройтись одними указателями по динамическому двумерному массиву.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS  10
#define COLS  20    

int main(void) {
    int** mat = new int*[ROWS];
    for(int j = 0; j < ROWS; ++j)
         mat[j] = new int[COLS];

    int** ptr = (int**)mat;
    int** end = (int**)mat + ROWS;

    int* e;
    while(ptr != end) {
          e = (int*)*ptr + COLS; // конечный запредельный адрес текущего массива
          for(int* i = *ptr; i != e; )
              *i++ = 0;
          ++ptr; // смещаемся к следующему массиву
    }

    for(int r = 0; r < ROWS; ++r)
        delete[] mat[r];
    delete[] mat;
    return 0;
}
```

Другое дело статический двумерный массив: вот как раз тут элементы матрицы расположены в памяти друг за другом.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS  10
#define COLS  20    

int main(void) {
   int mat[ROWS][COLS];

   int* ptr = (int*)mat;
   int* end = (int*)mat[ROWS];

   while(ptr != end)
       *ptr++ = 0;
   return 0;
}
```

Dexter384, так что в твоём вопросе никакой экономии на спичках не будет. В asm для удобства также есть индексация массивов, только индекс массива умножаем на размер типа, то бишь удобно чтобы лишний раз регистр не смещать туда-сюда. В С/С++ компилятор эту работу делает за нас, то есть умножает на размер типа, если доступ к массиву по индексу, а если через указатель — то смещение на n-байт (то есть на размер типа).

```
#include <stdio.h>


//asm(INTEL) x86 32-bits
int main(void) {
    int _arr[4];
    __asm {
         mov edx, 100
         mov ebx, 200

        lea esi, _arr

        // записываем в третий элемент массива по-индексу
        mov [esi+2*4], ebx

        // смещаемся ко второму элементу ++ptr
        add esi, 4
        mov [esi], edx
    };
    printf("%d\n%d\n", _arr[1], _arr[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

И последнее — для того, чтобы лишний раз куча не фрагментировалась, лучше использовать

```
int* mat = new int[ROWS*COLS];
```